# Show/hide div in foreach not working

Tags: c#, foreach, visible

We have menus we have created in Site Master.  We are assigning each employee a group ID so they could have 1 or 20 we want to do a foreach get that group # and show/hide the menu's based on which ones they have access too.  I can't seem to get .Visible to work with my string value because it says Visible isn't valid for strings so reaching out to see what I can do.  If i hard code menu1.Visible it works great but trying to do it that so I don't have to do a bunch of if statements just do one foreach and it shows all the menus if that makes sense.  Here is what I have  but can't get it to work.

```
// Get menus
    OleDbCommand getMenus = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT GRPID FROM LAEMPS WHERE EMPNO = '{empNo}'", cnDb9);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(getMenus);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string menuId = "menu" + row[0].ToString();

        menuId.Visible = true;
    }
```

ASPX

```
<li runat="server" id="menu1" visible="false">
                        <a href="#it" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> <span>IT</span> <i class="icon-submenu lnr lnr-chevron-down"></i></a>
                        <div id="it" class="collapse ">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li><a href="" class=""></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the aspx/html markup of your menu

Comment: A `string` indeed does not have a `.Visible` property.  What *does* have a `.Visible` property?  What object are you trying to target?  Is this Web Forms?  Are you looking to `FindControl()` with a given ID?

Comment: @mshsayem it's updated.. this is a asp/c# program just a list item trying to show/hide dependent on what we give access too.  I can do it with a if/else but just tying to have a better way to do things.

Comment: Like David said, try this: `FindControl(menuId).Visible = true;`

Comment: I think that will work.. I'm an idiot never thought of that I do that for Button's in gridviews.  That will work I'm sure thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

FindControl(menuId).Visible = true; is the golden ticket.  THanks for all your help